# foreach and or if array statement

Tags: php

I have a profile that shows profiles in a list. as shown in the image below.

[image]

**users** table

```
 id    |  email  |  full_name  |  job_title  | bio |  profile_photo
```

**images** table

```
 image_id  | id  | artist_img
```

**CODE**

```
<?php 

$db = dbconnect();
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT
 users.email,
 users.full_name,
 users.job_title,
 users.bio,
 users.profile_photo,
 images.id,
 images.artist_img
FROM users
INNER JOIN images ON users.id=images.id GROUP BY images.id');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

        $id = $row['id'];        
        $full_name = $row['full_name'];    
        $email = $row['email'];   
        $job_title = $row['job_title'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $ProfilePhoto = $row['profile_photo'];
        $artist_img = $row['artist_img'];    


        if (isset($ProfilePhoto) && ! empty($ProfilePhoto)) {
            $image = "$ProfilePhoto";
        } else {
            $image = "avatar.jpg";
       }

   echo "<div class='container team-wrap'>
           <div class='row'>
             <div class='col-md-6'>
                <img class='img-responsive' src='artist/$image'>
               </div>
                 <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                    <strong>$full_name<br>$job_title</strong>
                      <br>
                      <p>$bio</p>
                      <a href='mailto:$email' class='btn btn-info'>Contact Me</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class=\"container space team-wrap\">
           <div class=\"row\">
              <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
                    <div id=\"gallery-slider\" class=\"slider responsive\">
                      <div>";




                          echo"
                        <img src=\"gallery/$artist_img\" alt=\"\"></a>";  




                      echo "</div>
                    </div>
                  <hr>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
    }        
 ?>
```

**Problem area**

```
echo"<img src=\"gallery/$artist_img\" alt=\"\"></a>";
```

The issue I am having is that it repeats the profile for each image if the user has 5 images  it will add 5 profiles 1 for each img.

and does not show the other users profile at all. show how it shows up is look at the image for example its got 4 images under profile 1 and it shows there profile pic.. well it repats all that info for each image I want the pics that have the same id as the user to show up as a slider like below..

and it also refuses to show the other profiles of other users.

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: where is the code that returns the data from the DB?

Comment: @Gert added content

Comment: edited it just add $images variable in the top where you retrieve the other data

Answer (score 1):

yes because it is not seeing the variable because you echo it as text

```
echo"<img src=\"gallery/$artist_img\" alt=\"\"></a>";
```

should be

```
$r=0;
foreach ($images as $image.id){
    [$artist_img=$images[$r];
    echo "<img src=\"gallery/".$artist_img."\" alt=\"\"></a>"; 
    $r++;
    }
```

//

i don't like to echo to much html because very easy to make a mistake that way i prefer it is to stay in html and just echo my variable like the but that is just me

```
<html>
   <body>
      <a><img src="gallery/<? php echo $artist_img; ?>" alt=""></a> 
   </body>
</html>
```

do you see here you fetch the variable for the picture as single row

```
$artist_img = $row['artist_img'];
```

you need to make it a array because it is a array you must remember using inner generates a number of pieces of data, maybe for you it will be better to run 2 query second query loads the images.inner join is useful for some people but complex and dont really give any advantage because still searches the whole tables twice to get the results
something like this might work for for you

```
 $artist_img2=array();
//because there are more then one piece of data in it
$artist_img2 = $row['images']; 
//then you need to do another loop to put the data in variables or echo them out     
// in the loop
    //note the row refers to id and not image.id because in the inner array the key will be id 
     $artist_img3=row2['id'];
     echo "<img src=\"gallery/".$artist_img3."\" alt=\"\"></a>"; 
     //end loop
```

Comment: this is the same result artist image is not the profile pic its the images that the artist uploads your version gives same result only shows 1 image in the gallery when there is 5 in the database

Comment: if you are confused then please know your own code your posting. i can write a complete working code in 5 mins for this but this forum is not about writing code for others it is about solving errors